# Magento | After SSL Setup, Images not shown

Tags: images, http, ssl, https, magento

My problem is, i setup a Comodo Positive SSL on solempet.com
When i changed the options for front page to secure https urls, images and css now shown. 
I mean site is not load properly and images, css files and js files still comes from http address when i check.
I tried to define media and js urls for secure url. But it doesnt worked.

How can i pass this to show images and load css, js in https?
Im using 1.9 version of Magento.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's an error with your template supplying full HTTP URLs for image/css/js instead of relative paths. I had that same problem with Shopware templates. i'm afraid you have to edit all the offending URLs in the template file.

Comment: So how can i do that? And thank you ver much for your answer :)

Comment: Now i checked my theme provider, meigeeteam. They have an answer to someone who asked similiar question and they said "our themes works with ssl" I dont get this part.

Comment: it seems as if there are a few thumbnails and custom CSS includes included wrong, as far as I could see most of it is from a plugin called "revslider". so while your global template seems to do it right, the plugin's template seems to be wrong.

Comment: If you don't know about (and don't want to learn) HTML and PHP development in general and Magento plugin development specifically, you're pretty much screwed and your only options (apart from learning all that stuff) are either to get the plugin developer to fix it, or just stop using the offending plugin(s).

Comment: I cant understand this whole thing really but right now i refreshed the homepage and it load properly under https. Im surprised.

Comment: sorry, but no, it didn't: `The page at 'https://solempet.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://payments.intuit.com/payments/landing_pages/LB/default.jsp?c=VM&l=H&s=2&b=111111': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`

Comment: Yup i see. and ı understand what you trying to tell me, i have great team that i gathered but before they start working i thought i could be nice to give them few days for vacation :) So im dealing these non-relevant things for me but a week latr my team will be start to deal this things. Thanks for your helps, it works for me, for now :)

Answer (score -1):

I think its better to check css and static html blocks if you placed any images directly without using Magento getBaseUrl() or store_url="" structure.
Or check your website for SSL verified on - https://www.whynopadlock.com/

Comment: This isn't the proper way to recommend the use of a website here at Superuser.

Comment: I suggested solutions on how to check ssl for the images and media stuffs which are directly inserted without using structure and the website i mentioned is somewhat related to check the same. As ssl on browser will never show green until and unless all the url are not https. and website address i copied is not mine or i am not marketing it, i am developer and its my testing tool which i am recommending other to use if they are facing issue. If its not the proper way, just let me know and will try to follow the way you mention.

Comment: There exists meta.superuser questions on this subject